# Set property combining 3 dropdowns MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm attempting to set a DateTime property `Birthday` for a date of birth using 3 dropwdowns for Month, Day, and Year in MVC.  I am not able to get a valid ModelState at this point.  In addition, the `model.Birthday.[Month, Day, or Year]' values are not being recognized from the mark up.  Please help.

My markup is as follows:

```
@model StatisticalTracker.Models.RegisterModel

...

<li>
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Birthday)
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Birthday.Month, SelectListItemHelper.GetMonths(), "-- Month --", new { style = "display: inline-block" }) /
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Birthday.Day, SelectListItemHelper.GetDays(), "-- Day --", new { style = "display: inline-block" }) /
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Birthday.Year, SelectListItemHelper.GetYears(), "-- Year --", new { style = "display: inline-block" })
</li>
```

My ViewModel is as follows:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
   ...    

   [DataType(DataType.Date)]
   [Display(Name = "Birthday")]
   public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

My conroller is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
     if (model.Birthday.Month == 0 || model.Birthday.Day == 0 && model.Birthday.Year == 0)
     {
         ModelState.AddModelError("Birthday", "Date of birth is required");
     }
     else
     {
         DateTime dt = new DateTime(model.Birthday.Year, model.Birthday.Month, model.Birthday.Day);
         model.Birthday = dt;
     }
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         ...
     }

     // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
     return View(model);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create HTML Helpers for properties with public setters in the model - not for things derived from properties in the model. As Ric Notes - the DateTime.Year / .Month /.Day properties are readonly, and hence can't be bound.

What you should do is create a new viewmodel like:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
   ...    

   [Display(Name = "Birthday Year")]
   public int BirthdayYear { get; set; }
   [Display(Name = "Birthday Month")]
   public int BirthdayMonth { get; set; }
   [Display(Name = "Birthday Day")]
   public int BirthdayDay { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to implement validation to ensure the date is valid (ie ensure they can't pick 29th feb in a non leap-year etc) you'll need a custom validation attribute - this article looks pretty good: http://dotnetspeak.com/2012/05/validating-dependent-fields-in-asp-net-mvc

A simpler approach if you only need server side validation is to Implement `IValidateableObject` in your model class - eg: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/class-level-model-validation-with-ef-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-3

As an alternative approach - you could just have a single date field - but add a client side date picker - the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) one is pretty good. (The HTML5 `<input type="Date">` is another approach, but you can't guarantee that all clients support it)

One final option is to use an `<input type="hidden">` for the Birthday Date property, and have some client side javascript bound to the dropdowns which updates the hidden field when each of the dropdowns is changed.

Comment: I was trying to avoid having to save 3 separtate DB fields and concatenate them into one but I will try that if it is the easiest way

Comment: You don't need to store these fields separately in the database - the viewmodel can be a class you create just for this view. convert it before saving it to the database.

Comment: I was about to post this type of answer too. You have to have properties that have setters. It appears `DateTime.Day` is readonly and cannot be assigned to. This answer solves that issue.